# Set Nuget package version number in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, nuget-package

I am using TeamCity to build my solution and then package it up and add it to the TeamCity hosted Nuget Server.

The nuspec file has a version number added `<version>1.00</version>`, but I want this to be updated to be the same as the build number generated by TeamCity `1.0.564.9`. If nuget can only have 3 numbers, I do not mind losing the trailing `.9`.

In the TeamCity Build Step, I have tried adding the Assembly Info Patcher, but the file version showing in Nuget package manager is still 1.0.0.

I also tried setting the version number in the nuspec file to `<version>$version$</version>`, but I got a TeamCity build step error telling me that version was not defined.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I walked away from this and came back an hour later and the answer was obvious!

I had set the Build Number Format in the `General Settings`, but I had forgotten to set the Version number in the `Build Step`. I set this, ran the build again and the package now has the correct version number.